# How to programmatically navigate around a navigationController stack?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am just wondering how I could programmatically navigate around a navigationController stack?

I am familiar with the method:

```
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

as well as:

```
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

But could programatically go to ANY view controller in my navigation controller?

Please see my pic:

http://s18.postimage.org/iq1l4f721/test_xcodeproj_Main_Storyboard_storyboard.jpg?

I know I can segue to any view using the storyboard but am I right in thinking this would keep pushing new views onto the stack and eventually (in theory) I would run into problems?

Thanks

Carl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes , if you know the index of the controller in the stack or if you have a reference to it.
Like this:
`[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:index] animated:TRUE];`

Cheers!

Comment: or if you keep references to your view controllers in your app delegate then you dont even have to know their index.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned you must know it's index or have a reference to it. After all , that index is helping you to get it's reference.

Comment: oh, my bad, indeed you did, somehow i totally spaced out the last part of the sentence :)

Comment: this worked for views that are behind the one im currently on thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
for (UIViewController * viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[Number2Class class]]) {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: this also worked for views that are behind the one im currently on thanks :)

Comment: very welcome :) if you found a solution by the answers here, accept the answer. I suggest :)

Comment: I accepted the other one... though I could of accepted this one as well seeing as they both work... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to navigate to the desired viewcontroller

```
NSArray *vcs = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
    for (UIViewController *cont in vcs) {
        if([cont class] == [YOUR_VIEWCONTROLLER_NAME class])
        {
            NSLog(@"Class Found");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you read [`UINavigationController` Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?
2. `UINavigationController` has *property* `NSArray *viewControllers`, which holds current stack of view controllers (history).
3. `setViewControllers:animated:` - Replaces the view controllers currently managed by the navigation controller with the specified items. (overrides history)
4. `popToViewController:animated:` - Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack. (here you will need to pass an instance that exists in the history - *see above*)
5. Get back to #1...

Comment: Hi Poncha... yeah I had read the class ref... but I was getting a little confused... in my pic (first post) it looks like I want to go to a view controller that could not be in the stack (due to the path you would have to take to get to it)... so now im thinking that I need to push not pop

Comment: @CarlT yeah, if the view controller is still not there, you will need to push it, and then it becomes on top of the stack, and if you pop, you get back to the previous one.. Btw, when you pop a view controller off the navigation controller stack it's released - the ones on the stack are still consuming memory